# Getting Build errors regarding the fact that there are two partial _Default classes with page_load methods in them

Tags: c#, .net, saml, onelogin

I am trying to implement the OneLogin toolkit for c#/.net. I am using VS2017. The code behind files for the Consume.aspx and Default.aspx files that are part of the toolkit both have contain partial class _Default definitions and both contain page_load methods. This is causing a build error.

Error   CS0111  Type '_Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Please don't use the OneLogin tollkit for C#. It contains severe security vulnerabilities. Their own recommendation in the source is `This project was a proof of concept, not recommended to use it in production environments since it not cover all security checks that SAML demand.`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these things add boiler plate code to make it easier for you. Which may cause issues if the code has been duplicated.

The simple fix is, just remove the members files or what ever the duplication is you don't need that is causing the problem.

In your case there is a duplicate `Page_Load` just remove the most appropriate partial class, or members you dont need

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name `Page_load` on `_DEFAULT` method of `Default.aspx.cs` to `Page_Init`.